# Mapping a function that depends on the location of its input value to a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, mapping

Say we have an array,

```
arr = np.random.rand(3,3)
```

Usually when mapping a function an array, we are only interested in values of the array elements, ie

```
f = lambda val : val**2
arr_squared = f(arr)
```

But what if the output of our function depends on where the input value is located in the array, ie

```
f = lambda x,y,val : x*y*val
```

Right now I'm using meshgrids and ravel.

```
X, Y = np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

result = np.zeros(arr.shape)

for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)):
    result[x,y] = f(x,y,arr[x,y])
```

This works but is pretty slow. I'm having a hard time figuring out if there is a better/faster way to do this, and searches online have not yielded much useful info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, indices behave like any other arguments.

It all boils down to whether your function is vectorized or not.

If yes, as in your example:

```
>>> Y, X = np.ogrid[(*map(slice, arr.shape),)]
>>> def f(X, Y, val): return X*Y*val
... 
>>> f(X, Y, arr)
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.92796409, 0.20353397],
       [0.        , 1.01294541, 1.30677315]])
```

If not, as for example

```
>>> def g(X, Y, val): return X+Y if val>0.5 else X-Y
... 
>>> g(X, Y, arr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in g
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The quick fix is np.vectorize, but this is not fast:

```
>>> np.vectorize(g)(X, Y, arr)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 0]])
```

Better, if possible, manually vectorize:

```
>>> def gv(X, Y, val): return X + (2*(val>0.5)-1) * Y
... 
>>> gv(X, Y, arr)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 3, 0]])
```

Side note re your use of meshgrid: For indices you can abbreviate this using

```
Y, X = np.indices(arr.shape)
```

In the example above I'm using open grids which leverage broadcasting to save memory.